# How to integrate RoboSpice project to Android studio?

Tags: android, gradle, robospice

I'm android developer, and recently begin to work with Android Studio. Now i need use library RoboSpice (https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice). Explain please, how can i organize "build.gradle" file for using with library? What add to dependencies block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this steps:

1. Download library
2. File import module
3. Select your library and rename `:RoboSpice` for example
4. Go to `build.gradle` and write.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
......
compile project(':RoboSpice')
.....
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just add `compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:x.y.z'` where x.y.z is RoboSpice version.

Look at [Setup for Gradle users](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Setup-for-Gradle-users) for more information.